# usage of generics in flutter dart

Tags: dart, flutter

Can somebody explain the usage of `<MyApp>` ?

MyAppState is extended of State class , but what is MyApp?

I know OOP in php but can't understand this one.

```
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget{
  @override
  MyAppState createState() => new MyAppState();
}


class MyAppState extends State<MyApp>{
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(...);
  }
}
```

Comment: Check this post, it's perfect to understand what you need: https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-widgets-deep-dive-part-1-square-peg-in-a-round-hole-generics-in-dart-358eadb23d2d

Comment: Check this post too. https://dart.academy/generics-in-dart-and-flutter/

Answer (score 5):

Always remember that `State<T>` class is implemented as a generic class

when you extend any generic class you have to specify the type for it  which happen to be your statful widget concrete implementation and its name is `MyApp`

for every concrete implementation for the `StatfulWidget` class you need to define another concrete implementation of a class extending `State<MyApp>` and its name is `MyAppState`  because `State<T>` is a generic class we code it as `State<MyApp>`

so as answer to your question

**MyApp** is the name of the concrete implementation of the class **StatefulWidget**

*StatefulWidget* -----> class not generic

*MyApp*  -------------> concrete implementation for StatefulWidget class

*State* -----------> generic class of

*MyAppState* --> concrete implementation for State

Hope that help ..

Answer (score 1):

`State<MyApp>` is a `State` class that is *specialized* for the `MyApp` class.  This allows it to have inheritable methods and properties that operate on or involve a `MyApp` widget.

For example, it allows [`MyAppState.widget`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/State/widget.html) to return the corresponding widget specifically as a `MyApp` widget instead of as a generic `StatefulWidget`.  This is important if you then wanted to call `MyApp`-specific properties or methods on the returned widget.

Note that this is necessary because Flutter uses [type-safe Dart](https://www.dartlang.org/guides/language/sound-dart) and tries to do as much static type-checking as possible to minimize the cost of doing type-checking at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

`<MyApp>` is a type parameter of generic type `State<T>`. Not sure whether php has generics, but essentially generics allows you to reuse 'generic' code over a range of different types and in the meantime it provides more type safety e.g. generics prevents you accidentally adding a `double` to a list of `int` (`List<int>`) for example. A native example, again, would be generic list `List<T>` where the same operation like `add` item to a list can be applied to a list of int (`List<int>`) or a list of people or a list of anything.

Maybe check out [this](https://www.dartlang.org/guides/language/language-tour#generics) for generics in dart specifically.